Paint cracking around windows
We have large windows with black framing in the livingroom and just gave them a fresh coat of paint. But we've immediately started to see cracking along the edges (possibly due to expansion from heat given our windows face west). I'm scared it'll be a source of bugs + looks ugly. Has anyone seen something like this?


Normal expansion and contraction.   It could have been worse with new black paint absorbing more sun's heat.  You can caulk the cracks, that is normal procedure.
If insects get in, they are getting in the structure and just using the crack to get outside the wall.

It is unlikely that this will provide a path for insects.
The classic solution, if this bothers you, is to bridge the gap with a thin bead of paintable caulk, then paint it. to match the wall. This provides a flexible junction between the materials.
